# Q. Mechanics' Books

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm going to face Quantum Mechanics for the first time. My Professor strongly suggests that I buy the following book: "Modern Quantum Mechanics" by Sakurai and Napolitano that he uses for his course. I found the second and third edition. Would you have any piece of advice about which one should I pick? Sometimes one is better than the other and not necessarly the last edition is the best one. Do you know the differences between these two?

Also, what other books would you recommend? I also found "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" by David J. Griffiths e Darrell F. Schroeter that it is usually recommended.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: May be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18667/